# How would I know when a client connects with this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
while (!Server.isShuttingDown)
{
   Server.client = Server.listener.AcceptTcpClient();
   Connection con = new Connection(Server.client);
}
```

How do I make it so that the server knows when the client is connected? I made a class for what happens when the client connects but that is useless 'till I make it so that it knows when the client connects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `AcceptTpcClient` method will block until a client connects - so insert a line between that and the `Connection` constructor call... or even after it, assuming that the `Connection` constructor starts a new thread.

Mind you, it looks like you're *overwriting* the value of a single variable variable - `Server.client` - on each iteration, which doesn't sound like a good idea. I suspect you'd be better off with:

```
while (!Server.IsShuttingDown) {
    var client = Server.Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    // Act on "client has connected" here
    Connection con = new Connection(client);
}
```

(It's not clear why the `Server` object itself isn't doing all of this... or at least exposing an `AcceptTcpClient` method itself. Currently this looks like a bit of a violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).)

Comment: I made another class for it because I wanted it to run on it's own thread.

Comment: @MarcusS: Those two concerns are orthogonal - and you could still provide an `AcceptTcpClient` method in your separate class, to avoid having to expose the listener.